# How to restart rendering thread of GLSurfaceView (or what to do instead)?

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm experimenting with ways to do classical mobile game paradigm: a selector of levels, followed by a game screen.
*I fully understand that there are plenty of ways to do that*, but i was wondering about what goes wrong when i try this particular one (for learning purposes):

1. I have an activity, which holds references to my own GLSurfaceView child. On the activity start it loads a default 'level' and perfectly plays it. I can see Render thread started.
2. I implemented an OptionsMenu item, which after activation inflates a GridView with proper adapter, which allows user to select a level; and sets this inflated Layout to Activity by using setContentView. This is when GLThread dies.
3. Now i also implemented the OnClick's of that menu so that after click it loads a level in the game engine (works fine, btw) and brings back GLSurfaceView by using setContentView with saved (in 1.) reference.
4. And that's how i get a blank screen. Everything works fine, menu still works, i can go back to level selector, but in debugger i can see Render Thread doesn't exist.

Please, could someone explain to me **what exactly goes wrong** here? I'm totally not sure about this OpenGL intrinsic.

Comment: To a practical degree this is solved by recreating GLSurfaceView child everytime anew. But i'm still curious why is this different from 'pausing' activity? The logcat tries to tell me smth but i'm not sure..

Comment: I created a simple example to illustrate an issue:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2cd4

Comment: It appears that thread is stopped in OnWindowsDetached. And in never runs again, yep. I don't know why android developers made such a decision.

Comment: `GLSurfaceView` tries to do a lot of things for you.  Sometimes it does things you don't want.  It's not doing anything you can't do for yourself though -- it's really just helper functions and callback handlers wrapped around a `SurfaceView`.  If you don't mind doing your own EGL context and thread management, you can make it work any way you like.  On API 14+ you can also use `TextureView`, which works a lot more like a normal `View`.